# How to reverse the lines of a huge file efficiently with limited main memory

Tags: reverse

How might I reverse the lines of a huge text file efficiently with limited main memory? What is an efficient algorithm to use?

Comment: What os, are you using, what programming language would you like to use?

Comment: @Daryl: does it matter? I am implicitly assuming the sequential reading of text file and the IO slowness. So I need to limit the IO operations as much as I can.

Answer (score 2):

Should start reading from End of file, then go backwards all to way to the top.

You can read the file one character at a time backwards.
Cache/save all characters until you reach a carriage return.
Reverse the collected string and make it a line.

Comment: Is this the most efficient way? Please note I am rather memory limited.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you want to do, but have a look at the `rev` and `tac` commands (if you are on a system which has them).

Comment: As I said, it is not a question on "what tool I can achieve this". Rather, it is a question on "what algorithm I can use to get it done". Thanks.